# Minor GC but Eden space is not full

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Minor GC is used to clean Eden space, right?
but I used jstat to watch my GC logs.
There are 95% minor GC is occur when Eden space is 90% full.
However sometimes it happens by I find the Eden space is almost empty.

I use jdk7 and g1gc. My program handles fifty thousand requests per second. Every shortly pause cause by GC would be obviously.

For what other reasons would the GC decide to perform a minor collection?

Comment: stackoverflow is a community about **programming**, not system administration

Comment: @specializt I wouldn't consider the inner workings of the Java VM as system administration.

Comment: To answer that question we at least need to know what Java version and which collector you're using.

Comment: thats _precisely_ sysadmin - developers must not care about garbage collection whatsoever, if you need to care about it your software may very well be .... faulty in design.

Comment: @specializt `Developers must not care about garbage collection whatsoever`? That's an interesting suggestion, I wonder how you'd write high performance code without knowing how garbage collection works. (As an aside, a personal advice: I'd tone down the combativeness of my posts if I were you. It doesn't really make you come across as helpful.)

Comment: you actually "wonder" how to write high-performance code without caring about the GC? Wow ... i think you should'nt think about these topics just yet, you have obviously much to discover. It is **easily** doable to write maximum-performance applications without even thinking about GC once - thats because even the standard VM cleans up pretty efficiently, even if you generate tens of thousands of objects per second, it is nigh-impossible to outperform the GC and even _if_ you manage to do so you still can choose a more efficient VM, relying on GC manipulation is a major mistake.

Comment: even back in 1994 the GC was [pretty darn fast](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6622/AIM-1462.pdf?sequence=2) - and it got improved significantly since then. I think you should get yourself a good book about java.

Comment: @specializt Sure is the GC pretty good and most programmers should simply believe it's a magic device. But for performance above *your maximum*, you may [need more](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html#footnote-gc).

Comment: @maaartinus that is correct - but, honestly, if your requirements are **this** large one should at least consider switching to a low-level language in which problems like that arent actual problems anymore ... every language has its own purpose and "nigh-perfect performance" is not something which is written on Javas banner although it _may_ be possible

Comment: I use jdk7 and g1gc. My program handles fifty thousand requests per second. Every shortly pause cause by GC would be obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Jstat shows you *sampled* data. For example, if you run `jstat -gc <pid> 2s`, jstat shows you snapshots of the heap and gc states every two seconds.

Hence, eden could very well have been at 100% when the collection happened but the snapshot you saw in jstat was taken some time after a collection happened.

There are other explanations too, for example the G1 collector collects eden before it is 100% full. Allocation of a huge object could also trigger a gc when eden seems to be less than full.